# Exclude results on basis of test cases

Tags: mysql, join

Write a query to print the hacker_id, name, and the total number of challenges created by each student. Sort your results by the total number of challenges in descending order. If more than one student created the same number of challenges, then sort the result by hacker_id. If more than one student created the same number of challenges and the count is less than the maximum number of challenges created, then exclude those students from the result.

I have also attached the images for the respective tables

Table **Hackers**:

```
hacker_id name
     5077 Rose
    21283 Angela
    62743 Frank
    88255 Patrick
    96196 Lisa
```

Table **Challenges**:

```
challenge_id hacker_id
       61654      5077
       58302     21283
       40587     88255
       29477      5077
        1220     21283
       69514     21283
       46561     62743
       58077     62743
       18483     88255
       76766     21283
       52382      5077
       74467     21283
       33625     96196
       26053     88255
       42665     62743
       12859     62743
       70094     21283
       34599     88255
       54680     88255
       61881      5077
```

So, far I have done this

```
SELECT c.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(c.challenge_id) AS challenge_count
FROM Challenges c LEFT JOIN Hackers h on  c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
GROUP by 1,c.hacker_id HAVING challenge_count >= 
MAX(challenge_count) ORDER BY challenge_count DESC ,c.hacker_id DESC;
```

But not getting expected output. My output

[image]

I need to exclude duplicate results from output such as hackers with same number of challenges should be excluded.

Comment: So.. Who should be excluded here?

Comment: Hackers with same number of challenges should be excluded if there number of challenges value is less than the maximum value. If two hackers have same number of challenges and it is the maximum value, both the hackers need to be included

Comment: @sagi At least he's being consistent :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Lol, nice one for understanding, I'll upvote you just for that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several criteria here:

1. hacker_id, name, and the total number of challenges created by each student
2. sort your results by the total number of challenges in descending order.
3. If more than one student created the same number of challenges, then sort the result by hacker_id.
4. If more than one student created the same number of challenges then exclude those students from the result.
5. Except if the count equals the maximum number of challenges created,

The following deals with items 1,2, & 3...

```
SELECT h.*
     , COUNT(c.challenge_id) challenge_count 
  FROM hackers h 
  JOIN challenges c 
    ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id 
 GROUP 
    BY h.hacker_id
 ORDER 
    BY challenge_count DESC, hacker_id;
```

We can join this query to itself once, to resolve criteria 4, and again to resolve item 5, as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
           FROM 
              ( SELECT h.*
                     , COUNT(c.challenge_id) challenge_count 
                  FROM hackers h 
                  JOIN challenges c 
                    ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id 
                 GROUP 
                    BY h.hacker_id
              ) a
           LEFT
           JOIN
              ( SELECT h.*
                     , COUNT(c.challenge_id) challenge_count 
                  FROM hackers h 
                  JOIN challenges c 
                    ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id 
                 GROUP 
                    BY h.hacker_id
              ) b
             ON b.hacker_id <> a.hacker_id AND b.challenge_count = a.challenge_count
           LEFT
           JOIN
              ( SELECT h.*
                     , COUNT(c.challenge_id) challenge_count 
                  FROM hackers h 
                  JOIN challenges c 
                    ON c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id 
                 GROUP 
                    BY h.hacker_id
              ) c
             ON c.challenge_count > a.challenge_count
          WHERE b.hacker_id IS NULL  
             OR c.hacker_id IS NULL
          ORDER 
             BY challenge_count DESC, hacker_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.name,
       t1.hacker_id,
       COALESCE(t2.challengeCount, 0) AS challengeCount
FROM Hackers t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT hacker_id, COUNT(*) AS challengeCount
    FROM Challenges
    GROUP BY hacker_id
) t2
    ON t1.hacker_id = t2.hacker_id
WHERE COALESCE(t2.challengeCount, 0) IN
(
    SELECT t1.challengeCount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t1.hacker_id,
               COALESCE(t2.challengeCount, 0) AS challengeCount
        FROM Hackers t1
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT hacker_id, COUNT(*) AS challengeCount
            FROM Challenges
            GROUP BY hacker_id
        ) t2
            ON t1.hacker_id = t2.hacker_id
    ) t1
    GROUP BY t1.challengeCount
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) OR COALESCE(t2.challengeCount, 0) =
(
    SELECT MAX(t.challengeCount) FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS challengeCount
        FROM Challenges GROUP BY hacker_id
    ) t
)
ORDER BY COALESCE(t2.challengeCount, 0) DESC,
         t1.hacker_id
```

Comment: what is t2 here?? Table Challenges??

Comment: `t2` is just a table _alias_.

Comment: I tried executing your query but it only shows hackers with maximum number of challenges

Comment: Output for your query eliminated duplicates but need to order it using hacker_id and challengesCount in descending manner, also i need the hacker_id

Comment: Ty for your effort..but you did not pass the test case..result is not ordered

Comment: @AkashKR `result is not ordered` ... the results are most certainly ordered.  What ordering do you expect?

Comment: I need that hackers with maximum number of challenges should appear first duplicacy allowed..and hackers with less number of challenges appear second with no duplicacy..